# Error While Installing Pyaudio in windows 10

Tags: python

Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vo4omqnb\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vo4omqnb\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-667y35fv'
       cwd: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vo4omqnb\pyaudio\
  Complete output (9 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vo4omqnb\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vo4omqnb\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tl9zjqrp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vo4omqnb\pyaudio\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: Have you actually read the error? It is quite clear on what is needed

Comment: Hi there, please introduce the problem before you post any code, and include any steps you attempted that didn't work. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance on how to write good questions.

Comment: Thank You Issue Resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should install `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0` in this site https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

```
 C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vo4omqnb\pyaudio\
 Complete output (9 lines): running bdist_wheel running build running
 build_py creating build creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 copying
 src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 running build_ext building
 '_portaudio' extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.
 Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
 https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

these error messages indicate you to install `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0`

Answer (score 0):

Once try these commands in your prompt

pip install pipwin

pipwin install pyaudio

pipwin automatically installs required wheel for it.